# Concrete List type as parameter in java method

Tags: java

If there is a reason to make a parameter not generic,  is that a good approach?
Let's say I know in the method there takes place only access of members of list but not insertion should I force the developers to pass an ArrayList.

```
public void method(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    // ......
}
```

as you can see developers have to pass a list of type ArrayList otherwise they get error.

Comment: I think you mean "make the parameter type a concrete class rather than an interface". Either way, the type is generic (because of the use of `<...>` which specifies a type argument).

Answer (score 0):

> should I force the developers to pass an ArrayList.

IMO, no. The developer might use the list somewhere else. Only he knows the actual usage of the list and it should be up to him to choose the best list implementation. If there is no actual reason to enforce a specific implementation, you should always use the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are two good (albeit possibly rare) reasons I can think of to do this.

First, if you want to use a method that's only present in a specific implementation. `ArrayList` doesn't seem to have too many useful methods that aren't already specified by the `List` or even `Collection` interfaces, but it's still a possibility.

Second, which is a slight variation on the previous reason, is if you want to convey some performance expectations of your method. For example, both the `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` classes have a [`get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method. `ArrayList`'s implementation works in constant time (O(1)), while `LinkedList`'s is linearly dependent on the size of the list (O(n)). If your method relies heavily on this method, you may not want to allow calling it with a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with this is that the caller probably hasn't typed their `List` as an `ArrayList`, so even if they do have an `ArrayList`, they would probably have to write an explicit cast at every call-site. That would make the caller's code messier.

Another issue is that `ArrayList` is not the only class which implements `List` and supports random access in O(1) time. For example, [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) returns a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` object which is not an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`. Alternatively, for example if I want to implement a sparse `List` using a hashtable, such that `get` takes O(1) time but it's not an `ArrayList`, then I wouldn't be able to supply my list to this method even though it meets the performance requirements.

My solution would be to check the argument at runtime:

```java
if(list instanceof LinkedList) {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can either log a warning to inform about the performance issue, or (if you must be prescriptive), throw an `IllegalArgumentException` to say the method should not be called with a `LinkedList`. This means the caller's mistake would be detected at runtime rather than compile-time, but it should be detected the very first time it's tested, so that is no great loss.

Another option, of course, is to take an array instead of a list as your parameter. That won't be suitable for all purposes, but it's e.g. how the standard library's [`binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) method ensures it takes a sequence which supports random access in O(1) time.